# Forbidden access for django apache2 media files

Tags: python, django, apache, media

I have trouble with access my files from django admin site. I save files without any trouble, but when I try open it, I get error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /media/file.pdf on this server.
```

In django project settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/full/path/to/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In project urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my virtualhost I added this settings:

```
 Alias /static/ "/static/folder/"
 Alias /media/ "/meida/folder/" 
 <Directory "/static/folder">
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
 <Directory "/media/folder">
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

But still get this error. Where can be bug/mistake?
Edit 1: apache error log gives:

```
client denied by server configuration: /etc/apache2/home
```

Comment: try `sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/media/`

Comment: @itzmeontv Done. Still same error.

Answer (score -1):

Change /etc/apache2/conf-available/php5-fpm.conf. Replace every

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

The configuration has to be enabled by `a2enconf php5-fpm`.

EDIT

Follow the Basic Configuration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

EDIT 2

Do the changes and add this to your virtualhost settings:

```
<Directory /usr/local/django_apps/myapp/static>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note that the path is from the root!

Comment: But it's django(python) project. And in my /etc/apache2/conf-available/ folder php5-fpm.conf doesn't exist.

Comment: Project configured like in this tutorial, but error still exist. I don't kwon why when I try access media file i get 403 error, but with static folder all ok.

Comment: Tried this settings on media directory, but add this to static, maybe will help.